# iOS Debugging failed to load on Xcode due library security of CoreData module

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I was trying to simply debug my app while unit testing, but the variables weren't accessible. The error I was encountering was:

```
error: warning: Failed to load linked library Security of module CoreData - errors: Looking for "@rpath/Security.framework/Security", error: (null)
```

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be fixed by simply cleaning the "Build folder" (Shift+CMD+K). I'm sharing this weird behaviour, since I didn't see it shared anywhere else.